# Find the highest poin with conditions. Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

Need an algorithm to find the highest high with conditions.

We have Bollinger Bands (20,3) and ploted all candles that crossed the upper Bollinger band.There are too many such situations. Therefore, need to find the highest points among those candles that crossed the upper line and filter out those that are nearby marks from the highest high (left-right with a length of 5 candles) and plot shapes only on the highest one.

All I could do was just mark those candles that crossed the upper Bollinger bands...

```
//@version=5
indicator(shorttitle="BBM", title="BBM", overlay=true, max_labels_count = 500)
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
mult = input.float(3, minval=0.001, maxval=50)
basis = ta.sma(src, length)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
plot(basis, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.blue)
p1 = plot(upper, color=color.rgb(155, 39, 176, 30))
p2 = plot(lower, color=color.rgb(155, 39, 176, 30))

A = high > upper

plotshape(A ? upper : na, color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255),style = shape.circle, text = "A", textcolor = color.white, size=size.tiny, location=location.abovebar)
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple ways I thought of to do this, but I think this way makes the most sense. I created two new variables one for the highest high above the upper bb and one to keep track of the bar index.  I also created a label instead of using plotshape so you can remove previous ones if a new higher high is made within 5 bars.

```
//@version=5
indicator(shorttitle="BBM", title="BBM", overlay=true, max_labels_count = 500)
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
mult = input.float(2, minval=0.001, maxval=50)
basis = ta.sma(src, length)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
plot(basis, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.blue)
p1 = plot(upper, color=color.rgb(155, 39, 176, 30))
p2 = plot(lower, color=color.rgb(155, 39, 176, 30))

lenH = input.int(title="Length High", defval=10, minval=1)
lenL = input.int(title="Length Low", defval=10, minval=1)
highestHigh = ta.highest(high, lenH)
lowestLow = ta.lowest(low, lenL)

labelID1 = label.new(na, na, "",color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255), textcolor=color.rgb(255, 255, 255), style=label.style_xcross)

if high == highestHigh
    if high >= upper and high >= highestHigh
        label.set_xy(labelID1, bar_index, high)
        label.set_text(labelID1, str.tostring(high))
        label.set_size(labelID1, size.tiny)
        label.set_yloc(labelID1, yloc.price)

    for i = 1 to 5
        if str.tonumber(label.get_text(labelID1[0])) > str.tonumber(label.get_text(labelID1[i]))
            label.delete(labelID1[i])

        if str.tonumber(label.get_text(labelID1[0])) < str.tonumber(label.get_text(labelID1[i]))
            label.delete(labelID1[0])
```

Comment: Thank you! great idea. your version plot labels longer than mine, but mine is more accurate. How to merge our two versions? take a look at new version